# Flag intersection of two lists using LINQ

Tags: linq, set

I have two lists, one which is a subset of the other.

```
List 1: A, B, C, D, E
List 2: B, D, E
```

I'd like to end up with a single collection of the superset with items contained in the subset flagged.  This seems to be the sort of thing LINQ could do, but I'm not sure of the syntax.

```
Result: A, false
        B, true
        C, false
        D, true
        E, true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var list1 = new string[]{ "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" };
var list2 = new string[]{ "B", "D", "E" };
var result =
from a in list1
select new { Value = a, Has = list2.Contains( a ) };

foreach(var item in result ) {
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}, {1}", item.Value, item.Has);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var list1 = new string[] {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};
var list2 = new string[] { "B", "D", "E"};

var query = from item1 in list1
            join item2 in list2 on item1 equals item2 into g
            select new { Name = item1, IsFound = g.Count() > 0};
```

Comment: +1 - Particularly for large lists, a join will be more efficient than scanning list2 for each item. Note that g.Any() is preferred to g.Count() > 0.

Answer (score 1):

```
HashSet<char> subset = new HashSet<char>(list2)

var query = list1
  .Select(x => new
  {
    value = x,
    subsetHas = subset.Contains(x) }
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var list1 = new[] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" };
var list2 = new[] { "B", "D", "E" };
var result =
    list1.Intersect(list2)
         .Select(el => new { el, true })
         .Union(list1.Except(list2)
                     .Select(el => new { el, false }));
```